# Close StreamSource with File Parameter

Tags: file

i want to close  StreamSource , i tried this code

```
   try {
     sc = new StreamSource(xmlFile);
     // check stuff
   } finally {
   sc.getInputStream().close();
    }
```

but sc.getInputStream() return null

my code :

```
    File file = new File("C:\Users\Lenovo\file.xml");
    StreamSource sourceXml = new StreamSource(file);
```

after validation i want to close sourceXml

```
 try {
    File file = new File("C:\Users\Lenovo\file.xml");
    StreamSource sourceXml = new StreamSource(file);
    //validaion
   }catch(.....){
    }
   finally {
   sourceXml.getInputStream().close();
    }
```

i got nullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Java 7, you can use Automatic Resource Management to close the InputStream instead of closing it in a try-finally. For example:

```
try {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\file.xml");
    try (InputStream xmlStream = new StreamSource(file).getInputStream()) {
        //Validation
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    //catch errors
}
```

Here is some more information on the subject: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html

Comment: Thank you but the type of file must be Source 
because validate function has an input of Source

Comment: Source sourceXml = new StreamSource(new File(xmlFile));
//validation
//close
i don't know how to close sourceXml